# Python cannot see csv file

Tags: python, csv

I went through couple answers on forum already but without any success.
I am using Linux mint, Python 3.6.0 and i am trying to open CSV in Python but then error occurs:

```
  file = open("~/Desktop/xyz/city.csv", "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/Desktop/xyz/city.csv'
```

My code:

```
import csv

file = open("~/Desktop/xyz/city.csv", "rb")
reader =csv.reader(file)
```

I also tried to move the file to desktop as in some answers i found, instead of path i used "city.csv". Still doesn't work.

Completely new to Linux and just can't find why this isn't working.

Each reply appreciated!

Comment: How are you running the command?  Just form the terminal or from something like cron?  Possibly "~" is not expanding the way you think it should.

Comment: I am using Pycharm for running all code.

Comment: As you can see by the other answers, everyone thinks its the ~.  Try something like:

import os
print os.path.abspath("~") 

and see if thats what you expect

Answer (score 3):

You should'nt use '~' to specify the path of your directory but the full path instead. E.g. :

```
import csv

file = open("/home/user/Desktop/xyz/city.csv", "rb")
reader =csv.reader(file)
```

If you need to use the tilde, you should then use [`os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/xyz/city.csv')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser). E. g. :

```
import csv

file = open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/xyz/city.csv"), "rb")
reader =csv.reader(file)
```

The reason for that is that the "tilde expansion" is a user interface feature that is not recognized by the file system: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Tilde-Expansion

Comment: I've seen your comment for the other answer but I'm not allowed to type there atm. If you want to know the full path to access a directory under linux, use the command `pwd` which will print the full path to the current directory :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full file path, something like this:

```
file = open("/home/[username]/Desktop/xyz/city.csv", "rb")
```

Comment: It did the work, crap, i also tried /home/desktop but didn't thought of adding username there. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

Usually `~` does not expand properly. I have found that when it is needed, put `$HOME` environment variable value into a python variable and then use join to attach it as a prefix to the file name relative position. This also allows you to move the file to a different location and create a function that will allow you to redefine the prefix.